# Why I am not able to select more than 500 records (CiviCRM 4.6.10)?

Tags: search-results, actions

After a search, if I increase the no of records to more than 500, although I can select them, but when performing an action, it only applies to 500 records.

Could it be an issue with my PHP value or a known issue with CiviCRM?

[image: Example]

UPDATE: as you can see here, although I have increased the value at the bottom of page to 1500, and it shows 1500 records, but as I select them using the check box, it only shows ***500 selected Records only.***

Answer (score 1):

I checked and see the same limit when you select manually. So it seems not a PHP value. If you use the "All 1766 records" button you can exceed this limit.

Comment: So, is it a CiviCRM bug?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like 500 is the maximum number of rows the system will display, If you choose a number bigger than that, you'll see the bottom contact is still the same.

I'm guessing (not sure) this is hard coded for resource usage reasons. And given the system displays something like "Contact 1 - 600 of 10005", but only displays 500, seem to be a bug.